# Geo coding google maps API with udacity

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently started a google maps API course with Udacity, one of the questions involves geocoding and I have hit a brick wall with it.

the task that I have asked to do is "Using geocode WEB SERVICE request in your browser find the fun place that the following coordinate describes"

the coordinates being LAT:33.1262476 LNG:-117.3115765 the videos on the course didn't go into to much detail.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read about Google's geocoding API, and in particular the reverse lookup of lat/long coordinates -> addresses and/or named locations.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-example

For your case, it will be something like making a request to this URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&latlng=33.1262476,-117.3115765
```

Note that `YOUR_API_KEY` is something you'll have to create by registering a Google developer account (which is free).